# API error when requesting full size data from Alphavantage

Tags: alpha-vantage

I am working on analysing some historical stock market data for Australian shares. I am using Alphavantage as my API to get the actual data.

My problem relates specifically to the TIME_SERIES_DAILY function with FULL outputsize. For some shares, I receive an error message in response to an API call:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=SUL.AUS&outputsize=full&apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

{
    "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_DAILY."
}
```

If I change the outputsize argument to 'compact' it works but only returns a subset of data I am after.

The bizarre thing is that the full size response works for about 60% of the stocks I am after. After a bit of trial and error, I deduce that the API returns an error for specific shares everytime and not others.

I presume that there may be some feature about these specific shares that causes it to fail - I just don't know what.

Comment: I'm able to see the search for the stock with this call.

`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=SUL.AUS&apikey=XXXXXXXX`

As it returns the stock metadata and not the historical data, My assumption is that it's an internal bug. Contact their support email with this query. They might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known error with Alpha Vantage. See [here](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage/issues/183) for more details.

When there is an issue with data past 100 days, instead of returning bad data, it scraps the return as to not throw off algos.